# Input() is skipped in the thread, and it is fine without threading

Tags: multithreading, input, queue

Input no longer works after entering it twice

```
import queue
import threading

queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=5)

def t():
    while True:
        i = input()
        print('aaa',i, queue.qsize())
        queue.put(i, block=True)
threading.Thread(target=t).start()
```

outcome:

> 5
> aaa 5 0
> 5
> aaa 5 1
> aaa  2
> aaa  3
> aaa  4
> aaa  5

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the necessary code and still only entered it twice, after which input was skipped

```
import threading   

def t():
    while True:
        i = input() 
threading.Thread(target=t).start()
```